# SQL-запрос, выводящий еще и даты

Tags: sql, mysql

Такая задача. Короче есть таблица с датами `(TABLE dates)`:

```
id |    date
---+-------------
 1 |'2011-01-01'
 2 |'2011-01-02'
 3 |'2011-01-03'
...
31 |'2011-01-31'
```

Также есть таблица с графиком работы `(TABLE grafik)`:

```
id | den_ned | NAME
---+---------+------
 1 |   Sat   | John
 2 |   Sat   | Clair
 3 |   Mon   | Cliff
 4 |   Mon   | Tom
 5 |   Mon   | Linda
 6 |   Tue   | Neo
...
 ? |   Sun   | Alex
```

К примеру здесь сказано, что по субботам должны выйти на работу `John` и `Clair`; в понедельник -- `Cliff`, `Tom` и `Linda`; в воскресенье -- `Alex` и т.д.

Нужно составить запрос, чтобы он выводил еще и даты. Примерно так:

```
id |    date    | NAME
---+------------+-----
 1 |'2011-01-01'| John
 2 |'2011-01-01'| Clair
 3 |'2011-01-02'| Cliff
 4 |'2011-01-02'| Tom
 5 |'2011-01-02'| Linda
 6 |'2011-01-03'| Neo
...
 ? |'2011-01-31'| Linda
```

Так как `2011-01-01` суббота, то там 2 записи (с `id=1,2`). Далее, `2011-01-02` 3 записи (с `id=3,4,5`) и т.д.

Comment: Какая ужасная организация данных, надеюсь это вымышленный проект. И у Вас за субботой сразу идет понедельник ;)
А на счет запроса, сейчас подумаю.

Comment: Сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для мускула у меня получилось вот так:

```
SELECT d.date, g.NAME
FROM  `grafik` AS g, `dates` AS d
WHERE g.den_ned = SUBSTRING( DATE_FORMAT( d.date,  '%W' ) , 1, 3 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.date, g.name
FROM dates d
   JOIN grafik g ON g.den_ned = 
CASE WEEKDAY(d.date)
   WHEN 1 THEN "Mon"
   WHEN 2 THEN "Thu" 
         ...
END CASE
```

Comment: Извините, я немного не понял вашу мысль. 
> JOIN grafik g ON g.den_ned =
Имелось в виду `LEFT JOIN` или `CROSS JOIN`?
> CASE WEEKDAY(g.date)
`d.date` или `g.date`?

Comment: а) в SQL по умолчанию соединение закрытое, т.е. INNER JOIN
б) ?

Comment: Я ваш ответ потом перепроверю. Почему-то не выходит.

Comment: Возможно я заблуждаюсь, но по моему CASE можно использовать в SELECT, но не в WHERE.

Comment: Заблуждаетесь. CASE - это оператор (или функция, как например, считает для себя T-SQL), который возвращает скалярное значение. Его можно использовать в любой фразе